# Not able to save object value in Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is component class for example:

```
export class AppComponent {

  categories = {
     country: [],
     author: []
  }

  constructor(){}

  getOptions(options) {
     options.forEach(option => {
        const key = option.name;
        this.categories[key].push(option.value);
     })
  }
  
}
```

On clicking a button, I am calling `getOptions(options)` from different component. The structure of options looks like:

```
options = [
  {name: 'country', value: 'Germany'},
  {name: 'author', value: 'Franz Kafka'}
]
```

So now the value of `this.categories` will get updated, so now:

```
this.categories[country] = ["Germany"]
this.categories[author] = ["Frank Kafka"]
```

Value of `options` changes every time on clicking the button. When I am sending new `options` value such as:

```
options = [
  {name: 'country', value: 'Japan'},
  {name: 'author', value: 'Masashi Kishimoto'}
]
```

Old value for `this.categories[country]` is not getting saved for some reason. The new value for `this.categories[country]` should be `["Germany, "Japan"]` but I am getting only `["Japan"]` in the array.

Comment: Are you setting this.categories[country] (or [author]) to [ ] anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Mishi Mashina No, while declaration only I am setting them as [ ], not anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seems like the code is alright, even I tried through Javascript. What I can suggest is try checking the truthy value of options.value. It could be a possibility that there is some entry with no value options.

```js
let categories = {
     country: [],
     author: []
  }
  
let options = [
  {name: 'country'},
  {name: 'author', value: 'Franz Kafka'},
  {name: 'country', value: 'Japan'},
  {name: 'author', value: 'Masashi Kishimoto'}
]

options.forEach(option => {
        const key = option.name;
        console.log(key);
        if(option.value)
        categories[key].push(option.value);
     })
     
     
 console.log(categories);
```